# Unzipping without an app?

Tags: zip

This is a somewhat old phone running Android 2.3.6. My phone is not an English phone, so the below may not be exactly what an English phone would say.

I've downloaded a zip file to my phone that I want to unzip. When I click the file, the phone tells me no programs can complete that action. Which is true, as I don't have any apps that deal with .zip files. Except, I know the phone can do this without an app - I know this because it actually started to, and managed to unzip a few files before I hit the "back" button (on accident; I was trying to back out of something else when it popped the unzipping on me). I have those files in a directory next to the .zip file.

How do I tell the phone to resume unzipping?

Comment: You may not be able to *resume* but deleting the extracted files and trying to unzip again should do it.